# ssh failed when installing hadoop:connect to host master port 22: connection refused

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, ssh

I want to install hadoop cluster, the hostname of my computer is modified Master. I configure the ssh login without password, but I can only use ssh localhost successfully, when it comes to ssh Master, it shows ssh:connect to host master port 22: connection refused.  I don't know why

```
/etc/host
127.0.0.1 localhost
113.*.*.2 Master
113.*.*.31 Slave1

cd ~/.ssh
rm ./id_rsa
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cat ./id_rsa.pub >> ./authorized_keys
ssh Master
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@master
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@slave1
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```